# async await, process one item of For loop at a time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I can't seem to wrap my head around async await, let's say I want to process one item of an array at a time, with a 1 second delay:

```
    myfunction() {   
        clearTimeout(this.timer);

        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {              
            for (const item of this.myarray) {       
                 this.dosomething(item).then((res: string) => {
                     setTimeout(() => {
                         await this.final_thing_before_the_next_item.push(res);
                     }, 1000);
                 });
           }       
        }, 200);        
    }
```

Where would I put the "async"?

Comment: What does "with a one second delay" mean? Does that mean you wait for it to finish, then wait 1s and move to the next? Or you start an item, wait 1s and then kick off the next one, regardless of whether the first has finished?

Comment: this code isn't very clear to what you're actually trying to do.  async is used to mark a function as so, and await is used so you don't have to wrap the return of an async function with a promise

Comment: @EvanTrimboli wait for it to finish then pause a second before going to the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma618806956433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-overview-example.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

You can put an `async` inside the `setTimeout`:

```js
myfunction() {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    for (const item of this.myarray) {
      await this.wait(1000);
      console.log(item);
    }
  });
}

wait(timer: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), timer);
  });
}
```

Comment: Excellent, works great.  Putting the 'async' before 'myfunction()' didn't seem to do anything in this case, don't know why.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Now that you mention it, it shouldn't work if placed before `myFunction`. The function that contains the `await` must be the one preceded with async.

Answer (score 1):

In a simplified form, `await` is syntax sugar for consuming promises. The following snippets are pretty much equivalent:

```
doSomethingAsync().then(value => {
    console.log('it finished', value);
});

const value = await doSomethingAsync();
```

The caveat is that if you want to use `await`, you need to mark the function as `async`. I will assume you want to have a 1s delay after full completion. Your code might look something like this:

```
function wait() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
async function processItems(items) {
  for (const item of items) {
    const res = await this.doSomething(item);
    // This isn't processed until doSomething completes.
    const other = await this.doFinalThing(res);
    // This isn't run until doFinalThing completes.
    await wait(1000);
    // The loop now continues after waiting 1s.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process one asynchronous operation at a time, you could do the following:

```js
// "wait" for a 1000ms before resolving the Promise
const wait = (ms = 1000) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
  });
};

// array of asynchronous operations
const promises = Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) =>
  Promise.resolve(idx)
);

async function main() {
  const data = [];

  for (let item of promises) {
    const result = await item;
    await wait(1000);

    data.push(result);
    console.log("result", result);
  }

  console.log("final data", data);
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1):

you marked this as angular, so I'm going to say, consider rxjs...

```
// imports
import {timer, from, concat} from 'rxjs'
import {switchMap, delay} from 'rxjs/operators'


// wait 200 ms
timer(200).pipe(
  // switch
  switchMap(() => {
    // map array into streams
    const obs$ = this.myArray.map(i => {
      // from promise, do whatever
      return from(this.dosomething(i)).pipe(
        // switch again, to do final thing, again from promise
        switchMap(res => from(this.finalThing(res))),
         // delay 1s
        delay(1000)
      )
    });
    return concat(...obs$); // execute one after the other
  })
).subscribe(v => console.log('values 1 by 1, spaced 1s apart', v))
```

Comment: Got it working with one of the async examples somebody else provided but thanks for this, I haven't gotten too deep into rxjs yet but I've been meaning to

Comment: whatever works. recommend getting into rxjs ASAP if writing angular. it's core to the frame work. and async / await tends to be problematic in certain parts of the frame work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (and code sample) correctly, you basically want to

- Sleep 200 ms
- Iterate over a list of items. For each item you want to:

  - Call a function, passing the current item to it and getting a response in return.
  - Pause for 1 second.
  - Call a second function, passing it the response

To do that you need a `sleep()` function that returns a promise that will resolve when the specified time has elapsed:

```
function sleep(ms = 1000) {
  const p = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve());
  });
  return p;
}
```

Having that, you need an `async` function to do the actual work. It has to be `async` because that is what lets it `await` other things:

```
async function process_items( items, delayInMs = 1000 ) {
  for ( item of items ) {
    const res = await doSomething( item, delayInMs );
    await sleep(delay);
    await doSomethingElse( res );
  }
}
```

As you can see from the above bit of code, the advantage of using `async`/`await` over callbacks or promise chains is that it gives you a rather more succinct and declarative syntax.

Then you can wrap it all up in another `async` function:

```
async function myfunction() {
  await sleep(200);
  await process_items( this.myarray, 1000 );
}
```

Marking a function as `async` does two things: it

- Enables the use of `await` within that function, and
- Converts the function into a function returning a promise, regardless of what its ostensible return value is.

If you take this function:

```
function foo() {
  return 1;
}
```

and mark it as `async`:

```
async function foo() {
  return 1;
}
```

it is (more or less) as if you had changed to to read:

```
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, without looking at the specifics of your code is before myFunction ie async myFunction(). I see 'this' being used so I imagine this is a method of some object/class in which case that would be one way to go about it.